# bitbake recipe - doing a simple copy of the image

Tags: yocto, recipe, bitbake

I am attempting to write a recipe that would simple copy two files (MyfileA , MyfileB) to a specific directory when the overall image is built. This is what my directory structure looks like:

```
MyDir/MyRecipe.bb
MyDir/files/MyfileA
MyDir/files/MyfileB
```

I would like the two files to be copied to a folder in home (which would not exist initially hence the directories should be created)The folder lets say is called "Testfolder"
This is what my bitbake file looks like

```
DESCRIPTION = "Testing Bitbake file"
PR = "r0"

SRC_URI = "file://MyfileA \
           file://MyfileB "

do_install() {
        install -d  MyfileA ~/TestFolder/
}
```

Kindly let me know if I am doing something wrong here?
When i run bitbake on this I get the following

```
The BBPATH variable is not set and bitbake did not find a conf/bblayers.conf file in the expected location.
Maybe you accidentally invoked bitbake from the wrong directory?
DEBUG: Removed the following variables from the environment: LANG, LS_COLORS, LESSCLOSE, XDG_RUNTIME_DIR, SHLVL, SSH_TTY, OLDPWD, LESSOPEN, SSH_CLIENT, MAIL, SSH_CONNECTION, XDG_SESSION_ID, _, BUILDDIR
```

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, to create your own meta-layer, you should run command `yocto-layer create MyRecipe` in your Yocto Environment.  This is to make sure that you have all the necessary element in your meta layer.  Make sure to put the new meta-layer into conf/bblayers.conf

Creating HelloWorld Recipe Video can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HsaoVqX7dg)

Second,  to copy a file from one to another directories.

```
DESCRIPTION = "Testing Bitbake file"
SECTION = "TESTING"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"
PR = "r0"

SRC_URI = "file://MyfileA \
           file://MyfileB "

#specify where to get the files
S = "${WORKDIR}"

inherit allarch

#create the folder in target machine
#${D} is the directory of the target machine
#move the file from working directory to the target machine

do_install() {
        install -d ${D}/TestFolder 
        install -m ${WORKDIR}/MyfileA ${D}/TestFolder
}
```

To get more in details, this is my understanding of how the files move around in Yocto.

You have a directory that stored metadata in `/sourced/meta-mylayer/recipes-myRecipe/`.  In that directory, there would be a folder with the same name as the recipe. I.E. `myRecipe/` `myRecipe_001.bb`.

You would store the files that are related to `myRecipe.bb` (usually it is a patch) in `myRecipe/` so that `SRC_URI` will get into that `myRecipe/` directory to grab files. I.E. `myFileA`, `myFileB`

Then, you specify the `S`.  This is the location in the Build Directory where unpacked recipe source code resides.  By that mean, `myFileA` and `myFileB` are moved/copied to there when `myRecipe` builds.

Usually, `S` is equal to `${WORKDIR}`, this is equivalent to `${TMPDIR}/work/${MULTIMACH_TARGET_SYS}/${PN}/${EXTENDPE}${PV}-${PR}`

> The actual directory depends on several things:
>
> TMPDIR: The top-level build output directory
>
> MULTIMACH_TARGET_SYS: The target system identifier
>
> PN: The recipe name
>
> EXTENDPE: The epoch - (if PE is not specified, which is usually the case  for most recipes, then EXTENDPE is blank)
>
> PV: The recipe version
>
> PR: The recipe revision

After that, we `inherit allarch`.  [This class is used for architecture independent recipes/data files (usually scripts)](https://github.com/openembedded/openembedded-core/blob/master/meta/classes/allarch.bbclass).

Then, the last thing we have to do is copy the files.

`${D}` is the location in the Build Directory where components are installed by do_install task. This location defaults to `${WORKDIR}/image`

`${WORKDIR}/image` can also be described as the `/` directory in the target system.

Go to `${D}` directory and create a folder call `TestFolder`
Then, copy myFileA from `${WORKDIR}` to the `${D}/TestFolder`

P.S. Please add comment to fix. There might be mistaken information here, cause I learned all this by myself.

Comment: could you tell me what the value of WORKDIR variable is ? - Does this need to be an absolute or relative path ?

Comment: Also could you tell me what ${D} is ? Where is the value D assigned ?

Comment: The WORKDIR is defined as follow :  `${TMPDIR}/work/${MULTIMACH_TARGET_SYS}/${PN}/${EXTENDPE}${PV}-${PR}`. the path needs to be absolute. TMPDIR is in `/yocto-environment/build/tmp/` .[http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.0/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-WORKDIR]

Comment: D is the destination directory. The location in the Build Directory where components are installed by the do_install task. This location defaults to:    ${WORKDIR}/image.  When we do_rootfs, the stuff in ${WORKDIR}/image will be packaged together to create a rootfs.

Comment: You mentioned  earlier "Make sure to put the new meta-layer into conf/bblayers.conf" . The conf folder in my meta created projec only has one file in the config folder and its caller `layer.conf` where is `conf/bblayers.conf` ?

Comment: bblayers.conf should be in your BSPDIR/buildFoldername/conf/bblayers.conf.  local.conf is also in there.

Comment: So I tried placing the files myFileA and myFileB right next to the recipe and when I run bitbake on the recipe I get the message `WARNING: Unable to get checksum for myRecipe SRC_URI entry myFileA: file could not be found` Is there any place where the files need to be placed ?

Comment: ${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR} is in `poky/meta/files/common-licenses/`, you could find `MIT` license in there.  And, you do not put myFileA and myFileB in the same directory with the `recipe.bb`. It needs to be in the directory calls `recipe/`, example: https://github.com/meta-qt5/meta-qt5/tree/master/recipes-qt/demo-extrafiles

Comment: Thanks that helps - I'll give that a shot

Comment: I noticed in your example in the file `qt5-demo-extrafiles.bb` there is no mention of dir `qt5-demo-extrafiles`. How does bitbake know where to look for files in that case ? Does it recursively look in all folders present next to the bb script ?

Comment: It is set up that way, if you put `SRC_URI += "file://fileA "` in qt5-demo-extrafiles.bb. it would automatically go to `qt5-demo-extrailfes/` and look for fileA.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107272/discussion-between-james-franco-and-lightens).

Comment: I tried your method but when I add 'inherit allarch' I can't compile my recipe, I have the following error : 'gcc: error: none: No such file or directory'. Am I doing something wrong ? Thank you for your help