# copy some folders with files into a directory in recipe

Tags: yocto, recipe

I am creating a yocto recipe to compile and install my c++ program. This program needs some files I want to deploy in /home/root/my_folder

I would want to know how I can create that "my_folder" and how to copy those files. Lets say this is my recipe's structure:

```
root folder/
    Recipe_0.1.bb
    Recipe-0.1/
             recipe.cpp
             my_folder/
                   another_folder/
                         multiple jpg files
                   another_folder1/
                         multiple png files
                   fileA.txt
                   fileB.txt
```

What do I have to do to get this working?

This is what I am trying right now:

I guess that with:

```
SRC_URI = "file://*"
```

I get everything in my folder (files and other folders...):

```
do_install(){
     install -d ${D}${bindir}
     install -d ${D}$/home/root/myFolder
     install -d ${D}$/home/root/myFolder/myImages
     install -d ${D}$/home/root/myFolder/myImages/dogs
     install -d ${D}$/home/root/myFolder/myImages/cats

     install -m 0777 MyApp ${D}${bindir}
     install -m 0777 ${WORKDIR}/myFolder ${D}/home/root/myFolder
     install -m 0777 ${WORKDIR}/myFolder ${D}/home/root/myFolder/myImages/dogs
     install -m 0777 ${WORKDIR}/myFolder ${D}/home/root/myFolder/myImages/cats
}
```

I checked the log but I don't see any useful information about what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this question before, you can find it here: [bitbake recipe - doing a simple copy of the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36163173/bitbake-recipe-doing-a-simple-copy-of-the-image/36164901#36164901)

Recipe_0.1.bb will need to have `SRC_URI` to the files you need to copy.

```
DESCRIPTION = "Testing Bitbake file"
SECTION = "TESTING"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"
PR = "r0"

SRC_URI = "file://MyfileA \
           file://MyfileB "

#specify where to get the files
S = "${WORKDIR}"

inherit allarch

#create the folder in target machine
#${D} is the directory of the target machine
#move the file from working directory to the target machine

do_install() {
        install -d ${D}/TestFolder 
        install -m ${WORKDIR}/MyfileA ${D}/TestFolder
}
```

You can store the content on Git, or make it a tarball.  Below example is for git;

```
DESCRIPTION = "Example of data or configuration recipe"
SECTION = "examples"
LICENSE = "GPLv2"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COREBASE}/meta/files/common-licenses/GPL-
2.0;md5=801f80980d171dd6425610833a22dbe6"
SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/yoctocookbook/examples.git \
file://example.data"
S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
inherit allarch
do_compile() {
}
do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}
    install -d ${D}${sbindir}
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/example.data ${D}/${sysconfdir}/
    install -m 0755 ${S}/python-scripts/* ${D}/${sbindir}
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I can't get this working. I can't add all the files ony by one (I have about 30-40 images right now but I want to add about a hundred. I  will add what I have tried so far. I guess -d parameter creates a folder and -m parameter copy the file.

Comment: added example to add folders.

Answer (score 0):

this recipe worked for me and copied all the files i have in: ${THISDIR}/wlbin/

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}:"
SRC_URI = "file://*"

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}/lib/firmware/ti-connectivity
    install -m 0755 ${THISDIR}/wlbin/* ${D}/lib/firmware/ti-connectivity/
}
FILES_${PN} = "/lib/firmware/ti-connectivity/* "
```